Is there precedent for eventually dropping apostrophes from words? If so how long does it normally take for the word to evolve
During the evolution of the English language words are invented, stuck together to create new words and in some cases change meaning altogether. As such I would assume there are lots of words we use that either should theoretically have apostrophes but have evolved to not need them or never had them in the first place. As an example if I were to write the word "don't" without an apostrophe almost everyone would know what I meant but would also know it is incorrect.
Is there precedent for words to eventually drop apostrophes? If so what are some examples? Also in the case of don't, won't, can't, and similar words, do we think the apostrophe will ever get dropped and it still be considered an acceptable version of the word?

The playwright Bernard  Shaw left out apostrophes in many of his plays more than a century ago,  but it didnt catch on!

See Is it correct to say I write children books {not possessive case} for a discussion of the dropping of the apostrophe from the Saxon genitive in 'adjectival rather than true possessive' cases, like dogs home and working mens club. Also Shoe's Fowler quote here.

boatswain, bo's'n, bos'n, bosun; gunwale, gun'ale, gunnel; opossum, 'possum, possum; Halloweven, Hallowe'en, Halloween.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Does this answer your question? When did "phone" become accepted as its own word? When did phone start to replace 'phone?

@EdwinAshworth, the other question is only about the cases such as phone and bus, which are not readily generalisable to those like dont.

@jsw29 Are there other examples of this kind ? Cases like << writers guild >> and << working mens club >> have been well covered.

Yes, there is precedent for dropping apostrophes. Lots of words we commonly use today are abbreviations of the original words. Words like phone which is short for telephone, bus which is short for omnibus.
Originally those words were written with apostrophes in the place of the parts that were dropped. So telephone was originally shortened to 'phone before being eventually shortened to phone. Omnibus was originally 'bus before it was bus.

This is indeed true, but it is debatable whether it provides a precedent for something like dont. Not many people nowadays have omnibus in their vocabulary, and even those who do, probably don't think of bus as a truncated form of that word. Bus has become a word in its own right, which is why one doesn't feels the need to mark it with an apostrophe, even if one is generally pedantic about using apostrophes correctly. One, on the other hand cannot understand the meaning of don't without knowing that it is a short form of do not.

Phone, bus ... I'm not aware of many others. In fact no others spring to mind.

While *dont isn't an English word, cant is; I suggest that while homographs obviously do come into being, there's a bit of a barrier to creating a new one, so can't is unlikely to get shortened. (@jsw29)

@EdwinAshworth (inter-) 'net is the only addition I can think of. I've seen mentions of lab' for laboratory though I'm not convinced by them; forming contractions by dropping the ends of words seems common without apostrophes (e.g. photo) .  They seem more likely to be retained in the middle and dropped later on when used at the start of words.  Unfortunately Ngrams inserts a space between apostrophes/quotes and text, and of course searches including punctuation aren't easy at the best of times.  Searching a decent-sized corpus would give too many opening single quotes.

I'm not saying this is a strong precedent. There are unquestionably differences. But the question asked for any precedent, and for examples, so I gave them.

' As such I would assume there are lots of words we use that either should theoretically have apostrophes but have evolved to not need them or never had them in the first place. ' needs answering 'This seems far from the truth [with the apostrophe originally signalling an abbreviation rather than a Saxon genitive]', with a few examples that buck the trend.
